# double click on radio, switch value

Tags: wordpress, radio-button

I'm going to hide all "no" options on my inputs, how can I make works these radio like "checkbox"?
I mean, when I double click on them, they should switch to "no"

https://soundcollapse.com/contact/

Comment: Why do you use radio buttons at all, if you want checkbox functionality? You can style your checkboxes to look round and even add that effect.

Comment: must be radio because I have to integrate with mailchimp